# Ajax remove item after reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

So I created a little Ajax script which removes items from my database and view, unfortunately the view does only Change after a reload (item gets removed).

I could do a window.location.reload() in my success function, but I do not want to reload the whole page.

How do I handle this so that I do not have to reload the whole page and the item gets removed in the view.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".destroy-device").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
            }
        });
        $.ajax({
            url: 'destroy/'+id,
            type: 'post',
            data: {_method: 'delete',
                    id: id},
            success:function(data) {
                console.log('success');
            }
        });
      })
    });
</script>
```

html:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ $deviceValue->id }}">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger destroy-device" data-id="{{ $deviceValue->id }}" name="destroy_device">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
    </button>
</form>
```

Comment: What is your DOM like? Can't you just try a `$(this).remove();` in your success function?

Comment: Not sure what the issue is `$(this).remove()` or `$(this).hide()` or `$(this).slideUp()` seems to fit.

Comment: @Zenoo I tried that and it did not work somehow, no Errors in console

Comment: `$(this).closest("form").hide();` ?

Comment: Nope did not work

Comment: Unless you're not getting a `success` response, I can't see why the suggestions in the comments wouldn't work? (ie: `$(this).closest('form').remove()`).

Comment: @MelanciaUK I get the the success I cannot see aswell why this does not work, that is why I asked

Comment: Try `$(this).parent().remove();`. It's the solution for your current DOM. If it doesn't work, try console loging $(this) to see what you get.

Comment: @Zenoo yeah I did nearly the same like this: `$(this).parent().parent().remove();` and it worked

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a list of items (loaded from database) and you execute an ajax call to delete some of those items from the database.
You can return the deleted items' ids into the ajax callback and delete them from the UI:

HTML

```
<ul id="myList">
   <li data-item="1">Item one</li>
   <li data-item="2">Item two</li>
   <li data-item="3">Item three</li>
</ul>
```

jQuery

```
$.ajax({
   ...
   success: function(data) {
      // data --> Array of deleted items (data-item)
      if (data) {
         var list = $('#myList');
         for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
            list.children('li[data-item="' + data[i] + '"]').remove();
         }
      }
   }
});
```

You can do something similar with a table or another UI element